# Tally table columns Jquery

Tags: jquery, sum

I have a rubric style table with about 10 rows and 4 columns. I need the user to select either col 2, 3, or 4 (Col 2=5 points, Col 3=3 points, and Col 4=0 points), for each row.

Then, I need to tally the totals for col 2-4.

I can't even get the "selected" part right, so any help would be appreciated.

```
<table id="M3L1A1" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Points</th>
            <th scope="col">5 points each</th>
            <th scope="col">3 points each</th>
            <th scope="col">0 points each</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">1.</th>
            <td class="col2"></td>
            <td class="col3"></td>
            <td class="col4"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">2.</th>
            <td class="col2"></td>
            <td class="col3"></td>
            <td class="col4"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">3.</th>
            <td class="col2"></td>
            <td class="col3"></td>
            <td class="col4"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">total</th>
            <td id="colTotal2"></td>
            <td id="colTotal3"></td>
            <td id="colTotal4"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
$('#M3L1A1 tr').each(function(){
            $('td').click(function(){                   
                $('.selected').empty();
                $('td').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');
                $('.selected').html('X');
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you making the td click function inside a `.each` function?

Comment: So you are looking to have a user click a table cell to select it? One thing to start with that might help is to use a delegated event. Instead of adding 12 possible click handlers here, you can just delegate click handling to the `document`. All events bubble, so if you click a `td`, you actually are also clicking the `document`. As a first step, something like `$(document).on("click", "#M3L1A1 tr td", function(){ $(this).addClass("do-something"); });` works wonders. Also, no need for document.ready when you do it this way. Next, you'll need to designate which click will trigger the totaling.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
var points = [5, 3, 0]
$('#M3L1A1 tr:not(:last) td').click(function() {
  $('.selected').empty();
  $(this).closest("tr").find("td").removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  $('.selected').html('X');

  $('#M3L1A1 tr:last td').text("")

  $('.selected').each(function() {
    var inx = $(this).index() - 1;
    var td = $('#M3L1A1 tr:last td').eq(inx)
    var point = +td.text() + points[inx];
    td.text(point)
  })

});
```

**Demo**

```js
var points = [5, 3, 0]
$('#M3L1A1 tr:not(:last) td').click(function() {
  $('.selected').empty();
  $(this).closest("tr").find("td").removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  $('.selected').html('X');

  $('#M3L1A1 tr:last td').text("")

  $('.selected').each(function() {
    var inx = $(this).index() - 1;
    var td = $('#M3L1A1 tr:last td').eq(inx)
    var point = +td.text() + points[inx];
    td.text(point)
  })

});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="M3L1A1" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Points</th>
      <th scope="col">5 points each</th>
      <th scope="col">3 points each</th>
      <th scope="col">0 points each</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1.</th>
      <td class="col2"></td>
      <td class="col3"></td>
      <td class="col4"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2.</th>
      <td class="col2"></td>
      <td class="col3"></td>
      <td class="col4"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3.</th>
      <td class="col2"></td>
      <td class="col3"></td>
      <td class="col4"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">total</th>
      <td id="colTotal2"></td>
      <td id="colTotal3"></td>
      <td id="colTotal4"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly!